# Handling Exception thrown from Custom View Resolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I have a custom view resolver(s) and an exception resolver.
When an exception is throw from the controller code, the exception resolver is called and the exception is mapped onto the view with error message.

However, when I throw an exception from one of the view resolvers, it propagates up to the application server, and is not resolved with registered exception resolver.

I suppose this happens because exception resolver is 'below' view resolvers, since the views returned by it must be resolved... and so exceptions from view resolvers are thrown outside.. but still I do not know how to deal with that situation in a well-designed way.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when an exception resolver handles an exception thrown from a controller, it returns a view name so that the error page can be rendered.

So if a view resolver were to throw an exception, what could you meaningfully do with it? The error eventually has to be rendered in some way, but who's going to resolve that view, if not the view resolver itself?

To answer your question, I'm not aware of any mechanism to catch exceptions thrown by view resolvers, other than the standard servlet container mechanism. If you have error conditions within your view resolver, I suggest you either (a) fix them (if they're bugs), or (b) catch those exceptions *within* the view resolver, and render a different view displaying the error.

Comment: Thanks @skaffman for reply. I do need  a exception handler in ViewResolver as it is rendering some Google Closure templates inside that and that can throw some exceptions in case some rendering of the templates fails or it is unable to locate the templates somewhere.Can you suggest a way to render a different view inside the ViewResolver itself ?

Comment: @schhajed: So you're saying the exception is thrown from within the view itself, not the view resolver?  View resolvers do not render views, they just turn view names into `View` objects, which are then rendered separately.

Comment: yes, in my case View itself can throw the exceptions,because **View** is rendering the Google Closure template Objects, which may fail if not provided with proper input. Please suggest.